# ROS2 equivalent of ros::message_traits

Tags: ros-kinetic, ros-humble, rosmsg

I have a legacy code in ROS Kinetic Kame which needs to be reimplemented in RO2 Humble Hawksbill. The legacy code has few statements with ros::message_traits. While trying to find it myself, I stumbled upon `subscription_traits` and `rosidl_generator_traits` but got confused which is the correct equivalent.

Can someone let me know what is the equivalent of the same in ROS2?